# ES2017 NEST JS @IsEmpty Unable to resolve signature of property decorator when called as an expression.This expression is not callable. is not empty

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, class-validator, ecmascript-2017

Hi people im newer with Nest JS and i trying to add dto validator but for example when i tried to add isNotEmpty or Max compiler show me this error:

> Unable to resolve signature of property decorator when called as an
> expression.   This expression is not callable.

DTO:

```
import { Transform, Type } from 'class-transformer';
import { IsInt, isNotEmpty } from 'class-validator';

export class MessagesQueryDTO {
  @isNotEmpty()
  @IsInt()
  @Type(() => Number)
  readonly limit: number;
  
  @isNotEmpty()
  @Type(() => Number)
  @IsInt()
  readonly skip: number;
}
```

My config.json

```
{
  "exclude": ["**/*spec.ts"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you're trying to use these decorators? Without seeing the use, the error and config are useless

Comment: Maybe you're not importing these decorators from the class-validator library

Comment: Attach your dto code please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on Juan's answer, `isNotEmpty` is the internally used check from `class-valdiator` and can be used as a direct method. `IsNotEmtpy` (notice the capitalization) is the decorator, and should be used with `@` to denote it as a decorator.

Answer (score 4):

The isNotEmpty decorator should be IsNotEmpty with the first letter in uppercase.